# Ubuntu 16.04 and LUKS all partition

Tags: luks

I need to move old system (`/dev/sda`). Ubuntu 16.04 is LUKS partition. I would like to move the system (on `/dev/sdb`) so that all partitions (including `/boot`) are encrypted.

I have already copied the system to a new disk. Now I would like to encrypt boot partitions

```
$ lsblk 
NAME MAY: MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda 8: 0 0 10G 0 disk 
├─sda1 8: 1 0 500M 0 part /boot 
├─sda2 8: 2 0 1K 0 part 
└─sda5 8: 5 0 9.5G 0 part 
  └─lvm 252: 0 0 9.5G 0 crypt 
    ├─MDISK-swap 252: 1 0 500M 0 lvm [SWAP] 
    └─MDISK-root 252: 2 0 9G 0 lvm / 
sr0 11: 0 1 1024M 0 rom –
```

=================

I'm asking further :)

I created partitions /boot and encrypted. The system starts, but I need to enter the password for the boot twice. Any idea ?

```
root@ubuntusrv2tmp:~# lsblk 
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0    1G  0 disk  
└─sda1             8:1    0 1023M  0 part  
  └─boot         252:3    0 1021M  0 crypt /boot
sdb                8:16   0   10G  0 disk  
├─sdb2             8:18   0    1K  0 part  
└─sdb5             8:21   0  9.5G  0 part  
  └─lvm          252:0    0  9.5G  0 crypt 
    ├─MDISK-swap 252:1    0  500M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─MDISK-root 252:2    0    9G  0 lvm   /
sr0               11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

**parted**

```
root@ubuntusrv2tmp:~# parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1074MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1074MB  1073MB  primary               boot

root@ubuntusrv2tmp:~# parted /dev/sdb print
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 10.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 2      525MB  10.7GB  10.2GB  extended
 5      526MB  10.7GB  10.2GB  logical
```

**/etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
```

**/etc/grub.d/40_custom**

```
menuentry "Other Linux" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
insmod luks
insmod cryptodisk
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 1149241b-eac6-45b6-b926-c1d9ceddd4ae
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1149241b-eac6-45b6-b926-c1d9ceddd4ae
                fi
                echo    'Loading Other Linux TMask ...'
        linux /vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic root=/dev/mapper/MDISK-root ro
        initrd /initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
}
```

**blkid**

```
/dev/mapper/lvm: UUID="0HIkKp-s40v-KK61-yn79-Vwwg-sOIO-s4Jgys" 
TYPE="LVM2_member" 

/dev/mapper/MDISK-root:
UUID="bfe2f433-3249-4309-a13c-a8b1baffa64b" TYPE="ext4" 

/dev/sda1:
UUID="11486177-e7ca-4285-a34b-60c557759993" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
PARTUUID="d08c0112-01" 

/dev/sdb5:
UUID="30a2dd4e-9b46-42df-a363-8127372de1f7" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"

/dev/mapper/MDISK-swap: UUID="188b491f-5fdc-4d83-8f08-046becab333e"
TYPE="swap" 

/dev/mapper/boot:
UUID="1149241b-eac6-45b6-b926-c1d9ceddd4ae" TYPE="ext4"
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=1149241b-eac6-45b6-b926-c1d9ceddd4ae /boot           ext4    defaults        0       1
UUID=188b491f-5fdc-4d83-8f08-046becab333e              none          swap      defaults              0      0
UUID=bfe2f433-3249-4309-a13c-a8b1baffa64b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       2
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Could you please explain which source partitions and/or file systems you want to map to which destination partitions and/or file systems? A simple table or diagram might help in the illustration. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to inclyde the output of `sudo lsblk -f` (instead of just `lsblk`)? What's the current state of `/dev/sdb`? Is it empty or do you wish to reformat it entirely (losing all data currently on it)? Also, `/boot` can't be encrypted because it contains the instructions for the computer to ask for the decryption key and decrypt the other partitions with it. (Of course you can still encrypt it but you won't be able to boot the system with it.)

Comment: you can't encrypt /boot. Grub has to have access to it's files and can not decrypt a file system.